# IBM Fiber Storage

Tags: windows-server-2008, storage, hard-drive, ibm, fiber

I am asking this question on behalf of the company i work for, What the problem is that we have just setup a fiber storage system with an IBM Server and IBM Fiber Storage system, we brought the both systems second hand and the server works great but when we connect the fiber storage to it, it connects fine but when we put a hard drive into the storage bay it says IBM Uncertified disk. We are using the IBM Storage management software that is required but we are unable to save anything as it says there's  no disk installed (Due to the fact it's not certified)
How do i certify the disks?

The system is IBM - TOTALSTORAGE DS4100  / Disks - Sata FRU 39M4575

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Also, details.  What IBM fiber storage Storage system/array?  They make a few.  And what drives?

Comment: How do i certify the disks? 
The system is IBM - TOTALSTORAGE DS4100
disks - Sata FRU 39M4575

Comment: You purchase the disk from IBM.

Comment: But we already have the disks, they are just not certified..

Comment: The disks are not the ones that IBM sold with that controller, which is why they're uncertified.

Comment: They are? They have a stickers on them that says IBM then different codes e.g. p/n: 202988 and so on.

Comment: IBM had a specific set of hard drives that were sold for this model. Not all IBM drives are certified for use in all IBM storage. This system is so old that the lists of acceptable part numbers are no longer online, so I can't help you find them.

Comment: Thanks anyway, IBM said they have to send someone out to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck. The disks that you're trying to put in are not the ones that came with the DS4100 back when it was still for sale. You can try to find the part numbers for the disks that were sold for the system and try to find a place you can still buy them, but this system is so old that I wouldn't recommend it. Just cut your losses and replace this with something from this decade that still has information available for it.